# dev_appserver.py does nothing

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

Currently I'm new to appengine with python and now I'm following this tutorial. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/creating-guestbook#objectives
Somehow, when I run dev_appserver.py ./ as stated in the tutorial, it just does nothing.

[image]

And I already have my environment variables set up also.
[image]

Am I missing something? I use windows btw.

Comment: Did u clone the example code into your local directory?..Post your code as well

Comment: Yes, I cloned it. That's the path "d/PythonProjects/appengine-guestbook-python"

Comment: why do you have `/` at the end?

Answer (score 1):

I solved on it on my own guys. I was using gitbash so I switched to cmd and removed the slash at the end and it worked.